# Localizing StringLengthValidator does not get the right resource string

Tags: c#, wpf, data-annotations

I have the following code in my `DataContract` with the following validation attributes for the field LastName:

```
    [DataMember]
    [Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(PatientDataContractRes), 
            ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameRequired")]
    [StringLengthValidator(1, 50, ErrorMessageResourceName = "LastNameLength"
    , ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(PatientDataContractRes))]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
```

The Required attribute is working fine when I change the culture while running the application, but the StringLengthValidator seems to always get the default resource string. My app is in English and French and StringLengthValidator always returns the English text. Both attributes use the same resource. So why is it just working with the `Required` attribute?

Comment: Look out for typos in `LastNameLength` (in your code and resources, not in your question). I've seen far too many `Lenght` in my life.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem adding the CultureInfo in the constructor of PropertyValidatorCacheKey and fixing PropertyValidationFactory to use it

```
private struct PropertyValidatorCacheKey : IEquatable<PropertyValidatorCacheKey>
    {
        private Type sourceType;
        private string propertyName;
        private string ruleset;
        private CultureInfo cultureInfo;

        public PropertyValidatorCacheKey(Type sourceType, string propertyName, string ruleset,    CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            this.sourceType = sourceType;
            this.propertyName = propertyName;
            this.ruleset = ruleset;
            this.cultureInfo = cultureInfo;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.sourceType.GetHashCode() ^ this.propertyName.GetHashCode() ^
                   (this.ruleset != null ? this.ruleset.GetHashCode() : 0) ^ this.cultureInfo.GetHashCode();
        }

        #region IEquatable<PropertyValidatorCacheKey> Members

        bool IEquatable<PropertyValidatorCacheKey>.Equals(PropertyValidatorCacheKey other)
        {
            return (this.sourceType == other.sourceType) && (this.propertyName.Equals(other.propertyName)) &&
                   (this.ruleset == null ? other.ruleset == null : this.ruleset.Equals(other.ruleset)) &&
                   (this.cultureInfo == other.cultureInfo);
        }


    }
```